# Need help in understanding an linear algebra question.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Recently attended an exam and this question was asked.

[image]

How is it that `The figures (b) and (c) represent systems with no solution.` is a correct answer?

The three planes in figure b clearly intersect and thus they must have a unique solution. What is that I’m missing? Please clarify.

Comment: The three planes intersect pairwise not all together at same point/line. Any two of these equations do have solutions but a solution satisfying those two don't satisfy the third so all together don't have a common solution.

Comment: Thank you @TonyPizza please give an example (with equations) and post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Is (d) meant to represent the mustard coloured line overlapping with the black line over the entire mustard length or just overlapping at the two ends of the mustard segment?

Comment: d - colinear lines